# Scala - Why should I define a Stream with the keyword lazy?

Tags: scala, stream, lazy-evaluation

`Streams` are a lazy collection type by definition. But when I look at examples that make use of `Streams`, it seems that I still have to use the keyword `lazy` when I define them.

Example:

```
lazy val myStream: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: Stream.empty
```

Why do I need to do this? When I execute the following, I get the same result:

```
val myStream: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: Stream.empty
```

Comment: Do you think you *have* to do this only because of the examples?  Are you seeing any unexpected or errant behavior otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say much without seeing the specific examples you're referring to, but one reason to use `lazy` is to defer evaluation of the head of the stream. For example, note the differences between this:

```
lazy val myStream: Stream[Int] =
  { println("Evaluating head!"); 2} #:: Stream.empty
```

And this:

```
val myStream: Stream[Int] =
  { println("Evaluating head!"); 2} #:: Stream.empty
```

In the second case the message will be printed immediately, since `#::` evaluates the head of the stream. In any case you don't "have to" use `lazy` when defining streams—often having the head evaluated immediately isn't a problem or is actually the behavior you want.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *have* to declare `Streams` as `lazy`.  It is idiomatic for several reasons.

First of all, `Streams` are used when we want a collection to be as lazy as possible.  Using `lazy` allows for even the head of the `Stream` to be evaluated lazily:

```
def myExpensiveOperation = { println("computing..."); Thread.sleep(5000); 1 }

//Just declaring this stream variable causes the thread to sleep,  
//Even though we might not ever need to iterate through the stream
val stream = myExpensiveOperation #:: Stream.empty  

//Declaring the stream as lazy val solves this issue:
lazy val stream = myExpensiveOperation #:: Stream.empty
```

This can also prevent exceptions:

```
val stream = (1/0) #:: Stream.empty //Throws exception
lazy val stream = (1/0) #:: Stream.empty //Safe
```

Another issue at play here is memoization.  In order to defer execution as late as possible for many data types, it would be natural to use `def` instead of `lazy val`:

```
def streamDef = myExpensiveOperation #:: Stream.empty //No sleeping or printing!
```

The problem here is that `Streams` are smart about memoizing their results, but this requires us to have somewhere to store the information and a `val` allows us to do that.  So if we do:

```
streamDef.toList //Sleep and print
streamDef.toList //Sleep and print again!

streamVal.toList //Sleep and print
streamVal.toList //No sleeping or printing!  The results have been memoized.
```

So essentially `lazy val` gives us the ultimate deferred execution of `def` while preserving the memoziation abilities of `val`.  You can read more details about memoization of `Streams` in the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream).